Does mentioning someone’s sins somehow bring them before the heavenly court?
If someone has wronged you but you wish to forgive them.  Should one avoid talking about what they’ve done to you?

Seems like something an excellent Shofet could help with as there is a conservation principle at play, right?

I don’t understand your question?
